# Object rotation during export

Tags: mesh, export, import

The thing is, when I export the model (having previously applied all transform), the next time I import the floor, the model turns slightly, how can I fix it?

Before export

[image: Before export]

After the export, the next import

[image: After the export, the next import]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Blender uses floating point maths to define all it's numbers that locate an object. There is some limitations to floating point maths in the computing world so some extremely small errors can occur. Particularly when importing things.
For a more complete answer on why floating point numbers get rounded see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gIxbTn7GSc&ab_channel=b001

That rotarion differance is so small it's really not worth worrying about.